# How to specify GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN for the docker build command?

Tags: docker, github

I run this command

```
docker build  GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=my_token  -t "${IMAGE}" .
```

and got this error

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

But as you see above, I do have a dot at the end of the `docker build` command. Besides,   `docker build . -t "${IMAGE}"` works for me, so it seems the error is introduced at GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN part?

Comment: try:
`GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=my_token docker build -t "${IMAGE}" .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `build-arg`?

```
docker build --build-arg GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN=my_token -t "${IMAGE}" .
```